# QGIS 3 doesn't recognize Description from Value Map in attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, qgis-3, domains

I have some .csv files that defines Value Maps. When I set them in the Attributes Form panel, it shows the right values and description names according to the .csv files.

But as can be seen on screenshot, in attribute table are not shown description values, but only raw values. I searched at almost every settings panels, but I can't figure it out.

In QGIS 2.x it shows description values by default. Does anybody know whats the point of this problem?

[image]

Comment: It's a bug which will be fixed in 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Few week ago i have had the same problem. The problem for me was a space (or many space) in the values don't recognized. 
I advise you to check them.